# anylogic 7 "space type value: undefined" error

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to launch one of old models that worked in anylogic 6, but there is an interesting error:

```
    Invalid space type value: undefined
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid space type value: undefined
    at com.anylogic.engine.SpaceType$1.getAgentExtClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.setEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at automataproductioncell2.Robot.create_robotArm1_xjal(Robot.java:809)
    at automataproductioncell2.Robot.create_robotArm1_xjal(Robot.java:792)
    at automataproductioncell2.Robot.doCreate(Robot.java:1674)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.create(Unknown Source)
    at automataproductioncell2.Main.create_robot_xjal(Main.java:403)
    at automataproductioncell2.Main.create_robot_xjal(Main.java:384)
    at automataproductioncell2.Main.doCreate(Main.java:1507)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.y(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
    at automataproductioncell2.Simulation.executeShapeControlAction(Simulation.java:114)
```

As I can see, there is a call of SpaceType that has been deleted from version 7.0.0 (see http://www.anylogic.com/changes-history ).

I wonder what do I need to change - I see this problem first time et al.
I see that the name "SpaceType$1" is not ordinary name, but it is called in generated java code...

The project is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6tpi846g-FBNlBjaTNyS0huN3M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is caused due to space settings are locked for the Child agent type (Robot). It cannot be an environment (continuous or discrete) for the embedded agents if Parent agent type (AnimatedObject) does not play a role of an environment for any population of agents. However, GIS space is handled correctly because space settings are defined by GIS map. You need to put a dummy population of agents into the Parent agent type to resolve the problem.

Comment: i wonder how to do this but doing not dummy populations =)
thanks, it worked well for me